# Take user to a certain page based on login credentials

Tags: dreamweaver

Is there a way to take user to a certain page based excluivelly on his username and password during login procedure ? Example : If user John_Doe logs in he gets to see Page1.html. If Jane_Doe logs in she is taken to Page2.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this.   Here is a real quick and dirty one.   It may not scale well, depending how many users you have.

```
if($user == 'someuser){
     require_once('somepage.php');
} else if ($user == 'someotheruser'){
     require_once('someotherpage.php');
}
```

and so on...

Another option, if your application is database driven is to give each user an "access level" in the database, and then query that and return a different page depending on the access level, if you need to serve the same page(s) to groups of users instead of individual usernames.

Comment: How do you do that with access levels (query that and return a different page depending on the access level) ?

Comment: You'd need to be using some kind of database back-end.   Presumably, you would have a table in the database called "users" or something similar, with one unique row for each user.   You'd add a column called maybe ACS_LVL or whatever strikes your fancy, and give each user an access level.    The easiest thing would be to use an integer value here.   So if you wanted say 3 different levels of access, you'd populate the ACS_LVL column for each user with a 1, 2, or 3.    Then when your user hits your page, the query would be similar to: 'SELECT ACS_LVL FROM USERS WHERE USER = $_POST['user']'